# A term for Not Applicable in the context of UI/UX

Tags: american-english, british-english

I want to give an option to a user to check if an option is not applicable for her. However the two words in "Not Applicable" are too huge for my GUI. Suggestions Would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Not Applicable is often abbreviated as *N/A*

Comment: I dont want it to be NA - The app I am using it in is also applicable for children - would want something much simpler. Preferably a single word

Comment: Why don't you dynamically show or hide the the checkbox?

Comment: The question is like 1) Enter pet name 2) Enter Pet's purchase date/ birth date. If the user does not have a pet he should be given an option to say its not applicable. So the program flow is essentially going through every question without hiding anything.

Comment: What is "UI/UX"?

Comment: User interface and user experience

Comment: Perhaps ux.stackexchange.com would be a better place to ask?

Comment: You could start with a Yes/No question "Do you have a pet?". Only display the detail questions if they answer yes.

Comment: For Children, they won't know if the item doesn't apply (in the concept of not applicable.) They will know the answer of "Do you have"?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about fitting text into limited UI space.

Comment: No child who might have trouble with *n/a* will know  the pet's purchase date or birthdate.  Having said that the whole reason to automate surveys on the computer is so that the program flow can be adjusted based on prior answers - this is especially important when designing for children.

Comment: There is a Skip button for the questions, which essentially is a yes or no pattern. However I want to introduce this third option because if a person "Skips" a question, he can come back and fill it later. However if he clicks not applicable/do not have, this question will become void for him and will be omitted in the future. Somehow now I realize that its becoming more of  a UX question than a language question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try:

> **Doesn't apply**

(13 characters, including the space and apostrophe)

or

> **Not relevant**

(12 characters, including the space)

> **Not Applicable**

is 14 chars, including the space.

The space saved with either of my suggestions is therefore not enormous, but it might be enough for your purpose.

Comment: I think Doesn't apply fits my needs :)

Answer (score 0):

If there are two possible actual options, the third could be labeled  "neither". If there are three or more actual options, the "not applicable" choice could be labeled "none".

Comment: The question is like 1) Enter pet name 2) Enter Pet's purchase date/ birth date. If the user does not have a pet he should be given an option to say its not applicable. So the program flow is essentially going through every question without hiding anything.

Comment: How about No Pet? But make it a separate checkbox, so program can bypass the other questions if user checks No Pet.